# how to pass function to method parameter in java

Tags: java

APIResponse res = kpiAPIObject.getALLKPIDefinition(); --> function a

Boolean status = res.getNodeValues("shortName").contains(kpiName); --> function b

```
public void dynamicWait(function a,function b)
{
    long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while (t > System.currentTimeMillis() - 180000 ) {
        res = /* execute function a here */
        if(/* execute function b here */) {
            break;
        } else {
            Thread.sleep(30000);
            continue;
        }
    }  
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `if(res.getNodeValues("shortName").contains(kpiName)) {}`

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you could use some lambdas:

```
Supplier<APIResponse> a = kpiAPIObject::getALLKPIDefinition;
Predicate<APIResponse> b = res -> res.getNodeValues("shortName").contains(kpiName);
```

Then call them like:

```
APIResponse res = a.get();
if (b.test(res)) {
    break;
}
```

Comment: And the method signature would look something like: 
public <T> void dynamicWait(Supplier<T> a, Predicate<T> b)

Comment: In which case the first line would be `T res = a.get();`.

Comment: Lambda expression's parameter res cannot redeclare another local variable defined in an enclosing scope. in Predicate<APIResponse> b = res -> res.getNodeValues("shortName").contains(kpiName);

Comment: @Srikanta So rename `res` to something else.

Comment: still get the error ...Lambda expression's parameter res cannot redeclare another local variable defined in an enclosing scope.

Answer (score 3):

In Java, there are various ways. If you take a look at `java.util.function` package, you can see

- Function: Takes one argument, produces one result
- Consumer: Takes one argument, produces nothing.
- BiConsumer: Takes two arguments, produces nothing.
- Supplier: Takes no argument, produces one result.
- Predicate: Boolean value function of one argument

You can used them as inputs for your method and execute it within.

In you case, you will use Supplier for function a and Predicate for function b.

`Supplier<APIResponse> a = () -> { return kpiAPIObject.getALLKPIDefinition(); };`
`Predicate<APIResponse> b = res -> res.getNodeValues("shortName").contains(kpiName);`

```
public void dynamicWait(Supplier<APIResponse> a,Predicate<APIResponse> b)

{

long t = System.currentTimeMillis();

while (t > System.currentTimeMillis() - 180000 ){

            res = a.get();
            if(b.test(res)){
                break;
            }
            else{
                Thread.sleep(30000);
                continue;
            }
        }  

}
```

Comment: Lambda expression's parameter res cannot redeclare another local variable defined in an enclosing scope.  in Predicate<APIResponse> b = res -> res.getNodeValues("shortName").contains(kpiName);

Comment: @Srikanta rename it to something else like response

Comment: still get the error ...Lambda expression's parameter res cannot redeclare another local variable defined in an enclosing scope.

Comment: @Srikanta change to `Predicate<APIResponse> b = response -> response.getNodeValues("shortName").contains(kpiName);`